# Checking case sensitive file name HFS

Tags: objective-c, macos, hfs

Let's assume that we have a path /path/to/file that is lowercase.
Now on the file system the name of the file is /path/to/File.

How to check if file has correctly the same name.

```
NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error: 
NSFileManager fileExistAtPath:
```

all return YES for both cases. Is there a way to get file system represtentation of the path and compare strings or is there any other extended method to check if file exists with case sensitive name.

Answer (score 1):

HFS is case insensitive if not explicitly configured otherwise (which seems to be discouraged). This means that `/path/to/file` and `/PaTH/tO/fILe` are equivalent.

You can however enumerate the files in a directory and find the name of the file using

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/file"];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                  contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent
                  includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                  options:0
                  error:nil];
for (NSString* fileName in files) {
    if ([[fileName lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
        // fileName is the case sensitive name of the file.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and and get its "real" name (as stored in the
file system) with a `F_GETPATH` file system control call:

```
NSString *path = @"/tmp/x/File.txt";

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
int fd = open([fm fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:path], O_RDONLY);
if (fd != -1) {
    char buffer[MAXPATHLEN];
    if (fcntl(fd, F_GETPATH, buffer) != -1) {
        NSString *realPath = [fm stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:buffer length:strlen(buffer)];
        NSLog(@"real path: %@", realPath);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Swift version:

```
let path = "/tmp/x/File.txt"
let fm = FileManager.default
let fd = open(fm.fileSystemRepresentation(withPath: path), O_RDONLY)
if fd != -1 {
    var buffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(MAXPATHLEN))
    if fcntl(fd, F_GETPATH, &buffer) != -1 {
        let realPath = String(cString: buffer)
        print("real path: ", realPath)
    }
    close(fd)
}
```